# fancyBox and jQuery Deletion Tool Conflict

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've put together a script which creates [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/testing.php) image gallery page. I'm using 'fancyBox' to create the slideshow and a jquery demo originating [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html), which I've adapted to provide the deletion functionality.

The problem I have lies around these lines of my code:

```
<ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">

      <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->length; $i++) :  
                          $xmlFile = $descriptions->documentElement->childNodes->item($i);  
                          $name = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('originalname'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $description = htmlentities($xmlFile->getAttribute('description'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');  
                          $source = $galleryPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('source'));  
                          $thumbnail = $thumbnailsPath . rawurlencode($xmlFile->getAttribute('thumbnail'));  
                  ?>

                  <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="allimages" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" href="<?php echo $source; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>"alt="<?php echo $description; ?>" width="96" height="72"/>   </a><a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a> 
      <?php endfor; ?>  
      </li>
      </ul>
```

With the inclusion of these lines`:<ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">` and `<li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">` and their respective closing tags, the 'fancyBox' functionality doesn't work. Without them it works fine.

I'm relatively new to jQuery and I've been working on this for a few days now and I can't seem to find a solution.

I just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Fo additional information, I've added the 'fancyBox' script below.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">  

            $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                openEffect  :   'elastic',
                closeEffect :   'elastic',

                padding :   20,
                fitToView   :   true,

                prevEffect :    'none',
                nextEffect :    'none',

                closeBtn  : false,
                arrows : false,

                helpers : {
                    title : {
                        type : 'inside'
                    },
                    buttons : {}
                },

                afterLoad : function() {
                    this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                }
            });


</script>
```

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone that has this problem in the future:

gallery has a `display:none` set from the Jquery-UI example.

simply fix this line:

```
 <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">


 <ul id="gallery" class="ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put `<?php endfor; ?>`  after `</li>` not before.

Show how you wrote the Fancybox initialize script

Comment: Hi, many thanks for helping me with this. I've changed the above two lines around as you suggested, but unfortunately, the problem is still there. I've added the 'fancyBox' script to my original post, I hope this is what you need. Please, if there is anything else you need, don't hesitate to ask. Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Your deletion tool uses this function

```
// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
$( "ul.gallery > li" ).click(function( event ) {
 var $item = $( this ),
 $target = $( event.target );
 if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-trash" ) ) {
  deleteImage( $item );
 } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-zoomin" ) ) {
  viewLargerImage( $target );
 } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-refresh" ) ) {
  recycleImage( $item );
 }
 return false;
});
```

so this is preventing any action on the child element `<a class="fancybox">` bound to fancybox.

Maybe you can add another condition to bypass the `return false` if `$taget.is("a.fancybox")` like:

```
// resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
$( "ul.gallery > li" ).click(function( event ) {
 var $item = $( this ),
 $target = $( event.target );
 if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-trash" ) ) {
  deleteImage( $item );
 } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-zoomin" ) ) {
  viewLargerImage( $target );
 } else if ( $target.is( "a.ui-icon-refresh" ) ) {
  recycleImage( $item );
 } else if ( $target.is( "a.fancybox" )) {
  // do nothing and let fancybox to play
 } else {
  return false;
 }
});
```

Comment: Hi, sincere thanks for taking the time to reply to my post & help. I'm relatively new to Javascript so please feel free to speak down to me. I've tried your suggested code, & added a `})` to row 151 because I was receiving an error. Although I can delete the images, I'm unable to get 'fancyBox' to work. I've run this through Firefox & there is no error shown, so I'm not sure where the error is. I've updated the page associated with the link in my original post to show the new code. I just wondered whether you could possibly have a look at this & let me know where I've gone wrong. Kind regards

Comment: I don't see this `else if ( $target.is( "a.fancybox" ))` in your page/script

Comment: Hi @JFK, many thanks for continuing to help me with this and my sincere apologies for the mistake, it was a cut & paste error. I've now amended the code to inlude this line. The 'fancyBox' functionality  is now working, but unfortunately I am unable to delete any image. I receive a `Error 404 not found` message. I've run this through firefox, and other than the 404 message, it provides no further detail of the error.  |Kind regard

Comment: Hi @JFK, because I've now changed the gallery software which I'm using, I've accepted this answer so no-one else spends any unnecessary time on this post. Many thanks for all your time and trouble. Kind regards